# A subscriber error

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I tried to establish a subscriber in [move_action_capability](http://moveit.ros.org/groovy/doxygen/move__action__capability_8cpp_source.html#L140) in Moveit!

I established the subscriber within method "move_group::MoveGroupMoveAction::executeMoveCallback_PlanOnly" and following is my code to establish the subscriber:

```
ros::NodeHandle handle;
ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe("r_arm_controller/state", 1000, controllerStateCB);
```

This is my callback signature:

```
void controllerStateCB(const pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryControllerState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    for (int joint_index = 0; joint_index < 7; joint_index++)
    {
        current_joint_position[joint_index]=msg->actual.positions[joint_index];
        current_joint_velocity[joint_index]=msg->actual.velocities[joint_index];
    }
}
```

However, when I compile, I got the following error:

```
/home/pr2/moveit/src/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/move_action_capability.cpp: In member function ‘void move_group::MoveGroupMoveAction::executeMoveCallback_PlanOnly(const MoveGroupGoalConstPtr&, moveit_msgs::MoveGroupResult&)’:
/home/pr2/moveit/src/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/move_action_capability.cpp:203:91: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [23], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/home/pr2/moveit/src/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/move_action_capability.cpp:203:91: note: candidates are:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:379:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:390:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:438:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:448:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&)const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:498:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:509:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M)const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:559:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:570:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const MReq>&)const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:618:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(M), const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:663:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const T>&), const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:706:14: note: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const T>&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:752:14: note: template<class M, class C> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(C)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:785:14: note: ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(ros::SubscribeOptions&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:785:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

I have no idea what's wrong with my code to establish the subscriber.

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100871/a-subscriber-error/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-11-13**:
Seems like your controllerStateCB has the wrong type, can you edit the question and tell us how you instantiate it?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-11-14**:
Hi Thomas, I add my callback signature. I just noticed that there are three types of callback signature: functions, class methods, functor objects. I am using functions type here and I am not sure if it is appropriate to use this type here.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-11-14**:
Hi Thomas! It works! Thank you very much! But I am wondering why in http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29 tutorial, there is no "&" before callback function?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-14**:
@AdrianPeng Please don't use # in tags.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-11-14**:
I guess some gcc version may be tolerant on this point but when you set a callback you really are passing the function *address* and not the function itself. As there is no way to do the latter in C++03 (i.e. to express it through the syntax), compilers used to be more permissible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put a "&" in front of controllerStateCB ;)

```
 ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe("r_arm_controller/state", 1000, &controllerStateCB);
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To anyone reading [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/100871/a-subscriber-error/?answer=101681#post-id-101681) from @pelment: Callbacks *can* be class methods (which in many cases is preferable). You just have to put attention to setting it up in a way that the subscriber doesn't go out of scope (and use the syntax for class-callbacks from the publisher/subscriber tutorial).

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2